# top.location.href equivalent with redirect_to or render?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Is there an equivalent way to do a 'top.location.href' javascript-type redirect within a Rails controller? I want to ultimately do a before_filter redirect in a controller out of an iframe.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there's a built in Rails method to achive what you want. You could however render the javascript inline like so:

```
class FooBarController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :inline_redirect

  def inline_redirect
    if some_condition
      render :layout => false, :inline => '<script>window.top.location = "http://someurl.com";</script>'
    end
  end
end
```

I would imagine it's not really best practice though. You should really create a view and place the javascript in there. Note that some users might have javascript disabled, so you'll want to handle that scenario as well.

Comment: Kind of what I expected. Thanks!